# Using Drives to affect Two Shape Keys with One Bone

Tags: drivers, shape-keys, pose-mode

I have an object with 2 different Shape Keys to make an edge rise and fall, depending on the rotation of one bone. (see the Image)
[image: ShapeKeys]
One of the shape keys raises the edge, and the other shape key lowers the edge.  The problem is I have no idea how to set up the drives so that the bone effects them the way I want.
If this is not clear enough, let me know and I'll try and make my question more clear.  All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than use shapekeys, a hook was used instead because it's seen as an object, not a vertice.  You can use a driver on that. (Blend file below)

[image]

Both gable vertices are 'hooked' to the Empty and a simple driver expression is used to adjust it's transitions.  The bone's rotation in the Z axis is driving it up and down.

[image]

Select the hook, go into the Graph editor and in the Window's header, select 'Drivers'.
Select the strip at extreme left to see the expression and other settings in the panel called 'var'. (all lower case) (setup details are below)

Depending on your preferences, when the file is reloaded Blender may ask you (in the window's header) if you want to reload.  It won't work without that.  It's to prevent possible nasties (Python code) from running without permission.

### Setting up the Driver

Select the Hook and Right-click in it's Z LOCATION slot, and select "Add Single Driver"

Go into the Graph Editor and in the Window's header, open up the 'Drivers' window.  Press N to get the properties panel up and at extreme left, click on the Hook's strip.  That should open up the driver details as they stand.  Nothing is going to work until you do a reload from the Window's header.  As explained, you need that to allow your driver to run.

The one driver that's in there is called "var". (all lower case)
You can set that up to look at the Armature's rotation in the Z axis only and use that to take the current radial value of the bone and apply it to the height (Z axis LOC) of the hook.  As the bone rotates, it's degrees (value) changes and that's divided by 10 and tweaked with the "+.73" .  The expression you see in that slot is simply typed in.

[image]

Comment: Dude!  Thanks so much for the quick and awesome response!  It's perfect!

Comment: Thanks @RBlong2us . It's always a buzz to hear when people get there. :)

Comment: Keep up the good work, man! :D  Peace.